# Strong Signal ads are making it tough for me to use Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons

Few days ago I noticed a new phenomena in chrome

1) Whenever I visit a new website, the first click on the site results in a new tap with ads in it and directs me to a website called the theadsgateway.com.

2) When searching in Google, some weird results appear on the top of the page with label "Strong Signal ads"

3) When visiting some websites, three ads appear at the bottom of the page. Two squares and one is rectangular in the middle. Also with label "Strong Signal ads".

Following some instructions I found on the Internet, I uninstalled Strong Signal(which I don't remember installing) from Control Panel and removed the extension Strong Signal from Chrome Extensions. This didn't help and the three things I mentioned above still happen and whenever I restart my computer I find the extension Strong Signal in my Chrome extension like I never removed it before.

Please help.

Comment: http://malwaretips.com/blogs/ads-by-strong-signal-removal/#malwarebytes

Comment: You have malware.  The first step to remove is to delete the user profile for Chrome, after you backup, the important data files.

Comment: @crazypotato, Is this application safe to install?

Comment: @MrA1 Yes, both MalwareBytes and HitmanPro are safe to use.

Comment: @Ramhound, How do I do that?

Comment: @MrA1 - Locate the user profile for Chrome or delete the user profile for Chrome.  What have you done to figure it out yourself?

Comment: So, I installed MalwareBytes  and I pressed Scan it did detect strong signal and deleted then it restarted my computer. After restarting nothing changed and I still get these ads.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try Google's Software Removal Tool.

1. [Download Software Removal Tool](http://www.google.com/chrome/srt/)
2. Run it